# String substitution to detect empty variables?

Tags: bash, scripting, filenames, variable

I have a script that iterates through files and does some [string substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) to insert the date.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
f="/tmp/file.txt" # with .txt extension
timestamp="$(date +%H%M%S)"
echo "${f%%.*}-$timestamp.${f#*.}"
```

It provides the following output, which is correct.

```
/tmp/file-220304.txt
```

But if a file doesn't have an extension, the script breaks.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
f="/tmp/file" # no extension
timestamp="$(date +%H%M%S)"
echo "${f%%.*}-$timestamp.${f#*.}"
```

```bsh
$ ./test.sh
/tmp/file-220359./tmp/file
```

Isn't it possible to use something like `${f:-not found}` to fill in the blank if `f` is not defined? I can't figure out how to solve the above issue with the below method.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
f="/tmp/file" # no extension
timestamp="$(date +%H%M%S)"
echo "${f%%.*}-$timestamp.${f#*.:-not found}"
```

Results:

```
$ ./test.sh
/tmp/file-221420./tmp/file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd also have problems with `/tmp/dir.d/file` files.

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
f="/tmp/file.txt" # with .txt extension
timestamp=${(%):-%D{%H%M%S}}

set -o extendedglob
extension=${(M)f%.[^./]#}
print -r -- ${f%$extension}-$timestamp$extension
```

With standard `sh` syntax (would also work in bash/zsh):

```
#! /bin/sh -
f="/tmp/file.txt" # with .txt extension
timestamp=$(date +%H%M%S)

case ${f##*/} in
  (*.*) printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}-$timestamp.${f##*.}";;
  (*)   printf '%s\n' "$f-$timestamp";;
esac
```

With `bash`, you can replace `timestamp=$(date +%H%M%S)` with `printf -v timestamp '%(%H%M%S)T'` to avoid running that `date` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner, here is a demo of a somewhat ineligant but workable solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Test cases
FILE="/tmp/file"
# FILE="/tmp/file."
# FILE="/tmp/file.txt"
# FILE="/tmp/file.txt."

# TIMESTAMP="$(date +%H%M%S)"
printf -v TIMESTAMP '%(%H%M%S)T'

echo "${FILE%%.*}-${TIMESTAMP}.$([[ $FILE =~ \..*$ ]] && { echo "${FILE#*.}"; } || { echo "txt"; })"
```

The above adds `.txt` to the filename if missing an extension.

Use the following one-liner if you do not want a default extension added to a filename if missing an extension.

```
echo "${FILE%%.*}-${TIMESTAMP}$([[ $FILE =~ \..*$ ]] && { echo ".${FILE#*.}"; })"
```

Comment: @alecxs  Because I got the impression that is what the OP wanted. Easily modified to something else or no extension at all.

Comment: @alecxs.  If the filename contains a trailing dot, it is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

to keep it simple

```
#!/bin/bash
f="/tmp/file"
timestamp="$(date +%H%M%S)"
out="${f}-${timestamp}";
[ "${f%.*}" != "${f##*.}" ] && out="${f%.*}-${timestamp}.${f##*.}";
echo "$out"
```

to make it safe against `.` in path

```
dir=${f%/*};
file=${f##*/};
name=${file%.*};
suffix=${file##*.};
[ "$dir" != "$file" ] && dir=${dir}/ || unset dir;
[ "$name" != "$suffix" ] && suffix=.${suffix} || unset suffix;
echo "${dir}${name}-${timestamp}${suffix}"
```

remove the newlines if you need it in one line
note: i recommend to use full timestamp (date + time) to ensure it is unique

Comment: however, that still fails for *txt/txt* or *txt.txt*

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `f` isn't defined, it's that `${f#*.}` is the value of `f` with the the part until the first dot removed. If there is no dot, nothing is removed and `${f#*.}` is just the same as `$f`. Also, since it matches up to the *first* dot, you get issues with paths like `./foo.txt` (it gives `-181548./foo.txt`).

You'd need to either test if `${f#*.}` equals `$f` or use something like `${f#${f%.*}}`, which becomes empty if there is no dot-separated suffix. The counterpart for that would be `${f%.${f##*.}}`. Though you'll still have issues with `./file` again.

The problem with `./file` suggests splitting the filename part from the path first, and proceeding from there.

An alternative approach would use regexes. This works for the filenames I tested:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=$1
timestamp="$(date +%H%M%S)"
re='^((.*/)?[^/.]+)(\.[^/]+)?$'
if [[ $f =~ $re ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${timestamp}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi
```

That's `(.*/)?` -- optional path ending with a slash; `[^/.]+` -- initial part of filename; `(\.[^/]+)?` -- optional extension.